# One-Hot-Encoding with 0.20 version of Sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Since the update of the sklearn to version 0.20, my code for one hot encoding doesn't work anymore and I can't seem to find an answer how to fix it...

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [3])
X = onehotencoder.fit_transform(X)

# Avoiding the Dummy Variable Trap
X = X[:, 1:]

# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2, random_state = 0)
```

Comment: what is this line meaning? onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories = [3]). Please also share the what error you are getting so that its become easy to understand the context.

Comment: You can directly use one-hot encoding on the categories (No need to convert them to label encoder)

Comment: Sorry, it is categorical_features =[3]. I am trying to one hot encode 4th column in pandas data frame and I am getting the following error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'categorical_features'

Comment: Dear, You have used wrong arguemnt name  categorical_features. It should be  categories. please check the documentation. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html